# Accessing ORA_ROWSCN in the triggers body

Tags: oracle, trigger

Is it possible to access `ORA_ROWSCN` pseudo-column in the body of `BEFORE` triggers? I'm thinking about storing this value in the table itself to emulate SQLServer `rowversion` behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for contributing your answer :-) incidentally, why can't you just use `ora_rowscn` - why do you need to store it again in the table?

Comment: @ Jack Douglas: I tried to store `ora_rowscn` in the table as a separate column (similar to how SQLServer's `rowversion`works, so I don't need to change queries that use this feature while migrating from one RDMS to another).

Comment: I understand. You know about `rowdependencies` of course?

Comment: Yeah, I know that to have a row version, not a block version , table should be created with `rowdependencies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible (even if Oracle itself populates the value before launching BEFORE UPDATE trigger) - referring to `:NEW.ora_rowscn` in the trigger body generates error, `select ora_rowscn from table1 in the trigger` causes mutating trigger error.